# Unable to add foreign key between two tables tables on fields signup (uid) and login (uid)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I can't add foreign key between the tables on fields signup and login because of getting error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row:
a foreign key constraint fails
(`cems`.`#sql-109c_1ab`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-109c_1ab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `login` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without table definition???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to see how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to ask good questions. Also [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes when you are trying to add a row for which no matching row in in the other table.

The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table.

INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table it will reject